# Cosmos DB - Power BI Connection

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb

I am having issue accessing my Cosmos DB database using Get Data from Power BI and ODBC connection.

I am finally able to connect the database to Power Bi now, I am getting this error when I try to expand the Collections:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTxhW.png)

I followed the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/powerbi-visualize

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue with the Cosmosdb, its certainly an issue with your query, just double check your query.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/OLEDB-or-ODBC-error-Expression-Error-The-field-errors-of-the/td-p/155127

Comment: I am not using any custom queries, just importing directly from Cosmos DB.

Comment: I just ran through that tutorial this morning (and updated the screenshots - the changes will be live shortly) but I didn't run into an error like this. Is your account an Azure Cosmos DB SQL API account? Or are you using MongoDB or any other API?